# Difference between MailMessage.From and mailSettings-smtp-from

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient, mailmessage

I have to make all mails generated in the site to have same from address, BUT this should be configurable.

Can I leave the MailMessase.From empty so that it takes the From address from the following configuration.

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="no-reply@mysite.co.uk">
    <network host="mysite" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody here who could help me out, please?

Comment: It should work.. why don't you try it and see what happens

Comment: Yes, it does work, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MailMessage.From field is automatically set to the smtp from address during initialization.